# AWS Redshift LOCK WRITE and not READ

Tags: amazon-redshift

How can I do a `LOCK WRITE` on a table in a transaction that lets other connections perform SELECT operations ?

When performing this :

```
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE my_table;
<very long commands>
```

Other connections can't perform SELECT operations like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table;`

What I want to achieve is preventing others from writing while I'm writing, without preventing them from reading.

Comment: Might assist: [Managing Concurrent Write Operations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Concurrent_writes.html)

Answer (score 1):

Putting a LOCK to a table inside a transaction block, will not allow other users/sessions to read or write to the table.
If you want your transaction to be read only, you can use below syntax.

```
BEGIN [READ ONLY];
<very long commands>
```

If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.

Comment: What I want to achieve is "prevent others from writing while I'm writing" without preventing them from reading.